# AngularJS: Best way to create a typeahead if search result contains 200 Items?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-typeahead

I'm using **angular-bootsrap typeahead** to provide a search functionality. For some cases the search data is almost consisting of more than 200 items which is taking a lot of time to create the **DOM**.
What should be the best way to handle this amount of data?
I tried to create a custom typeahead template consisting of pagination, however I'm not able to see anything being created in the **DOM**.
This is where I stand :

**The HTML**

```
<td id="scrollable-dropdown-menu">
    <input type="text" ng-model="item.product" 
     placeholder="Search Product...." 
     uib-typeahead="product as product.name for product in searchProduct($viewValue)" typeahead-loading="loadingLocations" 
     typeahead-no-results="noResults"  
     typeahead-popup-template-url="customTypeaheadTemplate.html"
     class="form-control">
    <i ng-show="loadingLocations"  class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <div ng-show="noResults">
       <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> No Results Found
    </div>
 </td>
```

**customTypeaheadTemplate.html**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="customTypeaheadTemplate.html">
    <div class="">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" ng-show="isOpen() && !moveInProgress" ng-style="{top: position().top+'px', left: position().left+'px'}" style="display: block;" role="listbox" aria-hidden="{{!isOpen()}}">
            <li style="border-bottom: solid 1px lightgray" class="customFadeAnimate" ng-repeat="match in matches | startFrom:(currentPage*8)-8 | limitTo: 8 track by $index " ng-class="{active: isActive($index) }" ng-mouseenter="selectActive($index)" ng-click="selectMatch($index)" role="option" id="{{::match.id}}">
                <div typeahead-match index="$index" match="match" query="query" template-url="templateUrl"></div>
            </li>
            <div ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()" ng-hide="matches.length - 8 < 1" style="text-align:center;margin: 5px;color: #808080;min-width:250px">
                <span> {{((currentPage || 1)*8)-8+1}} to {{((currentPage || 1)*8 > matches.length) ? matches.length : (currentPage || 1)*8}} of {{matches.length}}     </span>
                <pager style="margin-top:-20px;margin-bottom:4px" total-items="matches.length" ng-model="currentPage" items-per-page="8" align="true" previous-text="Prev" next-text="Next"></pager>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </div>
</script>
```

**The JS**

```
$scope.searchProduct = function(viewValue){
      $scope.invalidProduct = false;
      if(viewValue.length < 3){
        return;
      }

      return $http.get('/api/v1/searchProducts', {
       params: {
         compId: user.companyId,
         name: viewValue
       }
     }).then(function(response){
       return response.data.map(function(item){
         item.quantity = 1;
         item.discount = 0;
         item.tax = 0;
         if(item.gst != null){
           item.tax = item.gst.rate;
         }
         item.subtotal = item.quantity * item.mrp
         item.subtotal = item.subtotal - (item.subtotal * item.discount/100);
         item.subtotal = item.subtotal + (item.subtotal * item.tax/100);
         return item;
       });
     });
   }
```

**Sample JSON (item)**

```
{
  "id": 858,
  "name": "COVER OIL FILTER",
  "mrp": 15,
  "sp": 0,
  "cp": 0,
  "stocks": 0,
  "isPublished": true,
  "partNumber": "15441KWS900S",
  "category": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "oil",
    "created_at": "2017-06-03T10:29:44.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-06-03T10:29:44.000Z",
    "company_id": 1,
    "tax": 0
  },
  "gst": {
    "id": 1,
    "rate": 28,
    "name": "87141090",
    "remark": "NULL",
    "created_at": "2017-07-22T14:28:38.000Z",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-22T14:28:38.000Z",
    "company_id": 1
  },
  "quantity": 1,
  "discount": 0,
  "tax": 28,
  "subtotal": 19.2
}
```

Comment: Yuck, no way to control backend max results? searchProducts?limit=10 or something? If not, maybe just call `.slice(start,end)` on it (before your map :)). At least you won't have to send all of it to the DOM / and process it. Not sure if this could help as well: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo

Comment: are you sure the DOM is slowing it down and not the server/DB time ? could you measure the time of query(db response - before db session and after) in server-side and time of response (network - before http request and after response ) in client-side

Comment: I second @ArielNahom. I seriously doubt that creating 200 DOM nodes takes a significant amount of time. If it does, then you might have to use something else than the angular-bootstrap-typeahead plugin, because it seems it was not intended for your use case and performs terrible with your data.

Comment: The 200 is just an example, the data will grow, also to curb the backend time I have implemented Elastic-search. I need to provide the soft-search for products, what do you propose?

Comment: as @Brian suggested, try to limit the results to 10, any autocomplete is only showing around 5-10 results. the limit is supposed to be at the db/elastic level. maybe this can help you https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html

Comment: I tried the pagination, for that I created a custom template, however it did not show anything in the DOM, I have mentioned that in the question.

Comment: the pagination is best at the db level not in the ui. if you retrieve huge amount of data and paginate it in the ui you still have long response time. how many records you get at the ui each keyup?